# Is there a difference between $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ and $T:F^n \rightarrow F^k$ in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone please tell me what is the difference between $T:F^n \rightarrow F^k$ and $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, I know that are both made to define a Linear Transformation but I never understood what is the $F$ stands for.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The $F$ usually stands for a general *field*; other common examples (besides $\Bbb R$) include the rational numbers, $\Bbb Q$, and the complex numbers, $\Bbb C$. Much of basic linear algebra isn't very different for different fields, but there are some important differences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: F stand for a field (such as $\mathds{Q}$ or $\mathds{C}$) - that is a set with two operations satisfying certain axioms (see any linear algebra textbook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ refers to real numbers, but $F$ is a general field.

Therefore, $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is a special case of $T:F^n\rightarrow F^k$, where $T$ transforms vectors from the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the vectors from the vector space $\mathbb{R}^k$.

In general, any set of object that have the following properties form a field:

0- Operations ($+$) (addition) and ($*$) (multiplication) are defined on the objects.

For $x,y,z\in F$, the following properties should hold:

1- Closure under addition and multiplication: $x+y, x*y\in F$

2- Associativity of addition and multiplication: $x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$ and $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z$

3- Commutativity of addition and multiplication: $x+y=y+x$ and $x*y=y*x$

4- Existence of additive and multiplicative identity elements: The should exist $0,1\in F$ such that $0+x=x$ and $1*x=x$

5- Existence of additive inverses and multiplicative inverses

6- Distributivity of multiplication over addition

Read more about fields [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-are-the-differences-between-rings-groups-and-fields).

Answer (score -1):

I guess $F$ is an arbitrary field. The real numbers $F=\mathbb{R}$ is just one example of [a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).

Other fields you know, are $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $F=\mathbb{C}$. But there are also other fields, for example finite fields (fields with only finitely many "scalars" in them).